# Investigate convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^5(\sqrt{8}+(-1)^n )^n}{8^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm homelearning calculus and trying to investigate the convergence of the following series:

> $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^5(\sqrt{8}+(-1)^n )^n}{8^n}$

however, I stuck. I tried calculating the limit of the summand, however I can't calculate the limit.

Can you help me determine whether in converges or diverges?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  Are you trying to find if the series converges or are you trying to calculate the sum.  As for the limit of the summand, it's asymptotic to $n^5/\sqrt8^n$ so it goes to $0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @saulspatz Well I want to verify whether it converges, absolutely converges or diverges.

Comment: It converges absolutely by the limit comparison test with $n^5/\sqrt8^n$

Comment: @saulspatz Could you please explain further? I'm not sure how did u get $n^5 / \sqrt{8}^n.$

Comment: The numerator is asymptotic to $n^5\sqrt8^n$.  Do you know what I mean by asymptotic?  It means that the limit of the ratio is $1$ as $n\to\infty.$  So, the fraction is asymptotic to $\frac{n^5}{\sqrt8^n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each term of the given series $u_n < \frac{n^5}{2^n}$
And $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^5}{2^n}$ is convergent from D'Alembert's ratio test.

Comment: Could you please explain how did u get $\frac{n^5}{2^n}$

Comment: Hint: $ \sqrt{8}+(-1)^n < 4 $ then $\frac{n^5(\sqrt{8}+(-1)^n )^n}{8^n} <\frac{n^5.4^n}{8^n} =\frac{n^5}{2^n}$

Answer (score 2):

Nimu's limit comparison method is easiest, but if you want to apply the ratio test directly, you can split the sum into odd and even $n$:
\begin{multline}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^5(\sqrt{8}+(-1)^n )^n}{8^n} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(2k-1)^5(\sqrt{8}+(-1)^{2k-1} )^{2k-1}}{8^{2k-1}} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(2k)^5(\sqrt{8}+(-1)^{2k} )^{2k}}{8^{2k}} \\= \sum_{k=1}^\infty(2k-1)^5 \left(\frac{\sqrt{8}-1 }{8}\right)^{2k-1} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty(2k)^5 \left(\frac{\sqrt{8}+1 }{8}\right)^{2k}.
\end{multline}

Now apply the ratio test to the resulting sums to see that they both converge.